# OnClose or OnExit function in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get a dynamic list of "Current Viewers" of over 50 Google Spreadsheets in just one master sheet. So far, I've got the code to run that inserts a new row using the onOpen function (just a row that records: user email, viewing document, date of entry, time of entry etc.) and I've also got the code to remove the entry when they exit - I just have no way of firing the code upon exit!

This is why I'm looking for an `OnClose()` or `OnExit()` function - just like the `onOpen` one. Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no onClose/onExit functionality in Apps Script.

Comment: There isn't a way around this either? The Google Spreadsheets show the number of viewers in the right pane. Is there any way I can tap into the number listed there?